# Style if text just have one line in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Css of:

```
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
 the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown</p>
```

Style will be different compare to text have just one line:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
```

Is it possible?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.  The length of the actual text in a paragraph doesn't effect the style of it.

However if you assign the paragraph tags within classes or id's then you can set each individual class or id to unique styles within the css style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want the line inside the paragraph to have a different style if so you can just add a span with an id to the area you want with a different style.

```css
#line{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span id="line">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span> of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
 the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to target a single vs multiline sentence in CSS, this is not possible.

If you want to restrict your `<p>` to just one line use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this programmatically with JavaScript.

Find the paragraph elements, check the length of the content and then apply a style based on that.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug1kznh1/3/) to illustrate (with jQuery).

HTML

```
<p>A short line.</p>
<p>A longer line with more words in it.</p>
```

JS

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
    if($(this).text().length > 15) {
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```